# How to deploy project and start Tomcat in IDEA properly

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, deployment, intellij-idea

I'm stuck with this problem for two days, I have some test projects (web service), I use Spring, REST(jersey), Maven and Tomcat.

I'm still not familiar with IDEA artifacts and therefore always have some issues when I try to deploy and run my projects.

Now, when I add my war file to webapp Tomcat's folder, it works, but when I start it in IDEA it doesn't work (I get 404 error), I searched a lot on internet, realized, that IDEA manipulates with paths when "communicates" with Tomcat (if I choose local Tomcat in run config), therefore I guess I have this problem, but I still dont know how to fix it.

BTW I use the latest IDEA: v14.

Comment: By default when you deploy WAR to Tomcat in Tomcat the URL of your application will be `localhost:8080/war-name` (unless you deploy it as `ROOT.war`). IntelliJ uses root context by default so your application should be available under just `localhost:8080`. Couldn't that be the problem? If this is not the problem please share the URLs you are trying to access the application under Tomcat and IntelliJ's Tomcat, screenshot of your run configuration or other info that might help diagnose the problem

Comment: shame on me)) i came at work this morning, decided to make some screen shots for you, guys, deployed again the project, start it and..it works now, whata?... that's great, but i still dont understand what was the problem and how i fixed it. Street magic so far.
BTW, you are right, in IDEA we dont need to add project name to link, actually i checked it before, it didnt work also yesterday!